# Does loading thousands of class in JVM impact performance on method execution

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I have created a `Bean` lets say

> com.session.implementation.MathOperationBean

and in that `MathOperationBean` lets say there are method `add`.

Now in my current company it is required to create one more such Bean file (its a long story so can not explain here why one more Bean is required) lets call that Bean as

> com.***v1_0***.session.implementation.MathOperationBean // (package is different)

Just for your information *v1_0* is a version number.

So the number of Bean files are double with double the number of methods. And there will be thousands of bean files for both the version which will be loaded in JVM.

**My question is:**
Does loading these many bean files in JVM reduce the performance of method execution in those beans?

Comment: It will make your jar/war bigger, but classes are loaded lazily and only the version in use will be loaded (unless you use both versions in your code of course).

Comment: The answer is that using more memory reduces the performance of the entire system, and that this is a poor approach to versioning.

Comment: @EJP thanks.. I agree with you, can you please help me with some new approach of versioning.

Comment: @assylias so you mean to say it will not have any impact on performance, as classes will be loaded lazily. But as far as I know when server is started the classes will get loaded

Comment: @Vishrant only if they are used - which we can't say based on the information you've given. If your program runs in an application server for example, it is possible that all the classes will be loaded during the exploration phase, when the server checks classes for annotations etc. But I agree with EJP that it looks like a weird way to do versioning...

Comment: @EJP, assylias: I agree that its not the good way of doing versioning but in my company it was done in order to maintain backward compatibility. The input param in the method was changed from int to long. Can you please suggest me what could have done in a better way?

Comment: Why are both versions loaded into the JVM at the same time? That doesn’t make any sense. Either, an application uses the old version or it uses the new version. Besides that, the question is looking at it the wrong way. The number of classes just doubled, nothing more. If thousands of classes were a problem, you already got into trouble with the first thousands…

Comment: Basically you should version the entire application, not individual classes. There are few situations where you need both old and new implementations at the same time. And I agree with @Holger that thousands of classes are already a problem regardless of versioning.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, no.

The JVM is very lazy, and will avoid loading or executing unused code paths. So if you have a thousand classes on your classpath but your application only uses ten of them you won't see (much of) an improvement by explicitly limiting your classpath to the ten used classes. Generally it's safe to let the JVM figure out what it needs; it's probably smarter than you.

You can experiment with this easily enough - add some libraries with lots of classes to your classpath and re-run your application. You should see no difference in performance.

More to the point there is no relationship between the efficiency of calling a specific method and the number of classes loaded by the JVM. In the same way that a hashtable remains O(1) regardless of how large it is, there should be (effectively) no impact on execution time based on the number of classes being loaded.

As @EJP points out there is a system-wide cost to applications that use more memory, but this cost is sub-linear (both the OS and the JVM will optimize where possible) so it's not something I'd spend a lot of time worrying about unless you have reason to believe it's a bottleneck.

There's nothing particularly special about versioned packages; by the sound of it there's still a fixed number of classes being loaded for each bean, meaning there's at most a fixed overhead per method invocation.

As the commentators point out there are code-quality issues with the package structure you're describing, but performance is not likely to be a huge issue.